# Chrome not showing updated page

Tags: css, image, macos, google-chrome, caching

I'm working on a Rails app and was updating a page.

The page has a whole bunch of background images defined in css.  When I refreshed the page (`cmd+r` on the mac), nothing changed.  When I went into the Chrome inspector and unchecked then rechecked the css rules, the images appeared.  Also, if I opened a new private browsing window (`cmd+shift+n`), the images all correctly displayed.

Am I running into some weird kind of cacheing issue?

Chrome: Version 21.0.1180.89

Mac OS X: 10.8.2

Comment: You need to do a hard refresh that bypasses the browser cache. I don't know the key combination on a mac, but it's probably similar to Windows: ctrl-shift-R. This is not the same as a normal refresh (ctrl-r on Windows) that does not bypass the cache.

Comment: seems to be `cmd+shift+r` on the mac, in case someone is reading this later.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Your answer is best. If you want to change it to an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to do a hard refresh that bypasses the browser cache. I don't know the key combination on a mac, but it's probably similar to Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>. This is not the same as a normal refresh (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> on Windows) that does not bypass the cache.

Aparently on a Mac the equivalent key combination is <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: This did not work for me. Not downvoting, just noting that there could be other solutions.

Comment: @JGallardo ... That's not a helpful comment. What browser? What didn't work, the suggested key combinations or the actual answer (hard refresh to bypass the cache)? What *did* work? Also recognize that this problem, and answer, are four years old....

Comment: Obviously we are talking about Chrome. Yes I realize your answer is 4 years old. But it still shows up when searching for this problem. Clearing my cache how you suggested did not work. What worked was the other answer to disable cache. And I uploaded a screenshot since vague text answers are terrible.

Comment: this combination command + shift + r worked for me. why did I have to do this to get chrome to update my new css changes? never seen this before. I even cleared all the history for the url before trying this. shouldn't chrome browser have a condition that looks for differences in css file? maybe that should be added to the chrome's bug list.  Thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas!

Comment: @Ian Browsers keep css in the local cache to speed up browsing. This is a feature because css and other assets are not expected to be rapidly or often changing. If you're doing web development, there's an option in the developer settings to disable the caching of assets entirely while the console is open to facilitate  the rapid reload of new resources. This isn't a bug.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas but would it be too expensive to check if a new css file has been uploaded to the web app? I did make a small css change to my website and didn't see the change until I did the manual refresh using cmd+shift+r. I think at the very least there has to be a condition that looks for any differences and if there are changes then pull in the new css file. going into the settings and disable caching of assets should fix this in the future as you suggested.

Comment: ctrl+shift+r, works for me, chrome version 60 in ubuntu. This performance bother me for some time. Even after delete the cache, the page is not updated, really noising when in local development. Thanks very much!!!

Comment: It worked!! I can't believe. I spent a long time searching for a solution and this little command made it work!

Comment: This solution, if it worked, would not resolve the real issue ... That of hundreds or throuands of other people who have this page cached on their machines, if caching is the issue.   You cannot run around force refreshing everyone's browers on the internet.

Comment: @rwg - True, but that's not the question. The question was, "I am developing an application locally, but my browser is showing a cached version; how can I force it to show my most recent changes?" It's *only* about local development.

Answer (score 6):

Try forcing the browser to load your new css file. I usually add a query string (?v=1.0) to the link, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1.0" "type="text/css"/>
```

and then I change the number (?=1.1) each time I've done some changes in the css file.

This usually fixes it in Chrome.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

I have this issue from time to time myself, especially when I am making lots of changes, I find clearing your browser cache works best, unless you have specifically set up some sort of caching.

Also make sure to check the "Disable Cache" is the inspector settings.

[image]

Screenshot taken October 10, 2016. Please update if changes have taken implemented by Google.

Comment: Do you know where the "Disable Cache" option is? I didn't see it on my first look through the options

Comment: Click the cog at the bottom right corner, and in the general tab is where you will find it.

Comment: Just wanted to mention this option can be found in windows by opening the developer tools ( f12 ), click the three dots icon on top right of the developer tools window and go to "settings". Scroll down and you should find "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"

Answer (score 1):

Command + Shift + Delete

Empty cache from the "beginning of time"